Connect Error SocketException: Connection failed (OS Error: Network is unreachable, errno = 101), address = 10.5.121.22, port = 5000
Problem with real device (in debbuging mode) and socketio in flutter>
it worked in emulator and web if i change the url.
the error: [log] Connect Error SocketException: Connection failed (OS Error: Network is unreachable, errno = 101), address = 10.5.121.22, port = 5000
But in the real device in debugging mode (using USB), it is not working! i put android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in androidManifest.xml and im sure i put the right ip of my pc.
i also tried Turning OFF the Wi-fi on real device but didn't helped me!

why would you turn off the wifi if you want to make a socket connection from a phone?
have you tried to access anything outside of your phone using the HTTP package? Have you check with the connectivity_plus package if your app ahs a network connection?
